# Trying to insert 2 files in database but "Notice: Undefined index: file"

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, forms

i'm trying to make a form to insert 2 files into oracle database but keep having these errors.

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00917: missing comma in "my files" on line 110
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in "my files" on line 111
>
> Warning: OCI-Lob::savefile(): Can't open file in "my files" on line 111
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in "my files" on line 112
>
> Warning: OCI-Lob::savefile(): Can't open file in "my files" on line 112

Anyway here is the code

```
          <?php
         if (isset($_POST['sbt'])) {
            ob_start();

            $unit = $_POST['unit'];
            $tanggal = date("y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['tanggal']));
            $noakun = $_POST['noakun'];
            $totalanggaran = $_POST['totalanggaran'];
            $penggunaan = $_POST['penggunaan'];
            $namaproyek = $_POST['namaproyek'];
            $diajukan = $_POST['diajukan'];
            $disetujui = $_POST['disetujui'];
            $dokumenform = $_POST['dokumenform'];
            $dokumennota = $_POST['dokumennota'];
            $unit = $_SESSION['id_unit'];
            $iduser = $_SESSION['id_user'];

            $insert = "INSERT INTO TMS_TBL_NOPES(ID_NOTA, ID_UNIT, ID_USER, TGL_PNGJN, NO_AKUN, NM_AKUN, TNA, SAAT_PENGGUNAAN, NAMA_PRO, PENGAJU, PENYETUJU, FORM, NOTA_DINAS) VALUES(URUTAN_SEQ.nextval, :unit, :idu TO_DATE(:tanggal,'YYYY-MM-DD'), :noakun, :totalanggaran, :penggunaan, :namaproyek, :diajukan, :disetujui, EMPTY_BLOB(), EMPTY_BLOB()) returning FORM, NOTA_DINAS into :dokumenform, :dokumennota";
            $send = oci_parse($conn, $insert);

            $lob_form = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
            $lob_nota = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);

            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':unit', $unit);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':idu', $iduser);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':tanggal', $tanggal);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':noakun', $noakun);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':totalanggaran', $totalanggaran);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':penggunaan', $penggunaan);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':namaproyek', $namaproyek);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':diajukan', $diajukan);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':disetujui', $disetujui);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':dokumenform', $lob_form, -1, SQLT_CLOB);
            oci_bind_by_name($send, ':dokumennota', $lob_nota, -1, SQLT_CLOB);

            oci_execute($send);
            $lob_form->savefile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $lob_nota->savefile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

            oci_commit($conn);
        }
      ?>
```

Could anyone find the errors and explain it to me?

Comment: The error messages tell you _exactly_ where to look. `$_FILES` doesn't have an index named `'file'`. So either you aren't uploading a file, or you've got the wrong field name. `<input name="myfile" type="file">` will result in the index `$_FILES['myfile']`. Simply check the contents of the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: @timclutton still not working for me